# Override Bootstrap 4 Form CSS Class Properties

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I am trying to style a checkbox in a web framework that uses bootstrap 4 by overriding the custom-control-label class and setting the position property to auto instead of relative. I can change the property in the browser's development tools and get the result I want, but when I add the style to my custom.css it does not override the property which is set in _custom-forms.scss. How can I override this property?

```
#form

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="custom_checkbox_name" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" id="id_custom_checkbox">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_custom_checkbox">
       <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
       <span class="custom-control-description">   Custom Checkbox Label</span>
  </label>
</div>

#custom.css

.custom-control-label {
    position: auto;
}
```

Comment: `position: auto` is not a valid property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: try to be more specific in you CSS rule add class attribute to your form and use in your CSS rule, then you have compile your scss file using the build script.

Answer (score 0):

Use **!important** to override

```
.custom-control-label {
    position: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `!important`, in this question case it can be overridden using CSS rules precedence: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html

Comment: its ok, we all been there once XD

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the !important to override bootstrap CSS properties

```
.custom-control-label
{
  position: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. at the end of my custom.css file without the need to use !important. Thanks for the replies.

```
.custom-control-label {
    position: unset;
}
```